# Persisting data client side between browser instances

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I am using chrome local storage data. I have used two types of storage in the browser, data in cookies and local storage. But after closing the browser it will automatically the data from the storage.

I am looking for a way to persist data client side between browser exit or browser updates.

For cookies I have tried this

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "John Doe";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
     echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

With local storage I have tried this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('email', 'test');  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried running Chrome without any plugins/addons?

Comment: As far as I know `localStorage` is not removed when you close the browser. So as mentioned it must be a plugin/addon issue most probably.

Comment: I have deleted all the plugin then also it is clearing all the data.Don't know why it is happened is there any dependency on browser setting ?

Comment: Yes i got this i can able to get the data from local storage even after closing the browser but can it will remain in the local storage after updating the browser version.